# Assistance with shutter release button on D300

Tags: nikon, shutter-release, nikon-d300

I have previously owned an n90 and still own a D100.  I have just purchased a D300 to upgrade my equipment.

I am having an issue I have never experienced before.  When I partially press the Shutter Release Button I get the focus, as usual, but when I press it completely I hear the click but nothing else till I click the Shutter Release Button again.

I feel like a duck out of water with this and do not know how to correct this to a single shot when depressed completely, as with my other camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is you have activated mirror lock-up function. Some of the camera operate on this way: On first press of shutter button the mirror lock up. On the second press of shutter button the camera make a photo. You can check for more details in to the [manual, page 93](https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/noprint/D300_en_noprint.pdf)

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you so much for your answer. Know I can use may camera!

Comment: @Marzolk rather than leave a "thank you" comment, please accept this answer by clicking the checkmate next to the answer.

Comment: Good catch Romeo